# Web App login from specific device only (hardware)

Tags: authentication, security, web, web-development-server, client-certificates

I'm developing a Web App which will provide a service to different client that purchase a subscription.
I'm being requested to find a way allow the login from only one device, so I need to find a "fix" the subscription to the device hardware.
¿What could be the best possible way for accomplishing this?
I've been exploring some options and one is using client certificates.Is there a way to make the client's device to generate a certificate based on hardware characteristics and send it to the server?

Comment: Is this one device going to be using this web app over the internet or a private network?

Comment: Its going to access the web application over the internet... I would like my application to check if the user is trying to login from a registered device, which will be the first device from where he/she logs in

Answer (score 0):

Talking about classic web apps where the client software is a browser/mobile app/desktop app and you only control the backend server, It's not possible to truly limit the login to one **specific** device/hardware because you don't own the client and in a http request every information can be altered.

If the generated machine id is breached (i.e. by the user) than it's possible to forge requests with it on other devices.

The best what you can do in this situation is to allow only one active session at a time and use some basic http header fingerprinting to filter out basic malicous user attempts.